# How do i stop the infinite loop for the if and elif part?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

```
c = random.randint(0,5)
guess =int(input("="))
while True:
    if guess > c:
      print("you failed the test")
    elif guess <c: 
      print("you messed up")
    else:
      print("you are the one" + x)
      break
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `break` in more than one place in the loop. It doesn't have to be in `else` block or anywhere in particular. This will still work:

```
c = random.randint(0,5)
guess =int(input("="))
while True:
    if guess > c:
      print("you failed the test")
      break
    elif guess <c: 
      print("you messed up")
      break
    else:
      print("you are the one" + x)
      break
```

This code doesn't make much sense though as the loop will never run a second time. You probably want to ask for input every time the loop runs. So you should move the `input()` call into the loop as well. It seems like you're looking for:

```
c = random.randint(0,5)
while True:
    guess =int(input("="))
    if guess > c:
      print("you failed the test")
    elif guess <c: 
      print("you messed up")
    else:
      print("you are the one" + x)
      break
```

Comment: well this is embarrasing now how do i delete my post?

Answer (score 0):

What do you think will happen when `while(true)` is present?

- The condition is always true and so the loop will never stop running unless it encounters a `break` statement. The `else` part works fine since it has a `break` statement.

What should you do?

- Add break statement in `if` and `elif` too so that the control moves out when condition is met.