# Break if elif loop when condition holds

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, break

**Set-up**

I scrape a ad names containing information I want to retrieve.

Example: `name_ad = 'quarto duplo brilhante em santa apolonia'`

Given the information in `name_ad` I define a variable `type` per ad.

Following is my code,

```
while True:            
    if 'cama de casal' or 'duplo' in name_ad:
        type = 'double'
        break            
    elif 'cama de solteiro' or 'único' or 'individual' in name_ad:
        type = 'single'      
        break
    else:
        type = ''
        break
```

which is based upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35518049/7326714).

---

**Problem**

I'm not breaking the loop correctly: for all ads I have that `type = 'double'`, which is not true.

How do I correctly break my `if/elif/else` loop?

Comment: The dupe explains further (and the why), but you need: `if 'cama de casal' in name_ad or 'duplo' in name_ad` etc...

Comment: Ah... Thanks Jon.

Comment: Also, you don't need an infinite while loop for this. You're breaking immediately after the loop starts, no matter what.

Comment: In addition to the issue discussed in the duplicate, you also probably don't need a loop at all if you're going to `break` out of it always on the first iteration.

Comment: Thanks guys. It's working now.